# Alinear Etiquetas en Circular barplot

Tags: r, diseño, packages

Tengo una consulta, este es el código de ejemplo que viene en la documentación de `ggplot` en **R**.

```
# library
library(tidyverse)

# Create dataset
data=data.frame(
  individual=paste( "Mister ", seq(1,60), sep=""),
  group=c( rep('A', 10), rep('B', 30), rep('C', 14), rep('D', 6)) ,
  value=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T)
)

# Set a number of 'empty bar' to add at the end of each group
empty_bar=3
to_add = data.frame( matrix(NA, empty_bar*nlevels(data$group), ncol(data)) )
colnames(to_add) = colnames(data)
to_add$group=rep(levels(data$group), each=empty_bar)
data=rbind(data, to_add)
data=data %>% arrange(group)
data$id=seq(1, nrow(data))

# Get the name and the y position of each label
label_data=data
number_of_bar=nrow(label_data)
angle= 90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) /number_of_bar     # I substract 0.5 because the letter must have the angle of the center of the bars. Not extreme right(1) or extreme left (0)
label_data$hjust<-ifelse( angle < -90, 1, 0)
#label_data$vjust = -10
label_data$angle<-ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)

# prepare a data frame for base lines
base_data=data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(start=min(id), end=max(id) - empty_bar) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(title=mean(c(start, end)))

# prepare a data frame for grid (scales)
grid_data = base_data
grid_data$end = grid_data$end[ c( nrow(grid_data), 1:nrow(grid_data)-1)] + 1
grid_data$start = grid_data$start - 1
grid_data=grid_data[-1,]

# Make the plot
p = ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group)) +       # Note that id is a factor. If x is numeric, there is some space between the first bar

  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +

  # Add a val=100/75/50/25 lines. I do it at the beginning to make sur barplots are OVER it.
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 80, xend = start, yend = 80), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 60, xend = start, yend = 60), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 40, xend = start, yend = 40), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 20, xend = start, yend = 20), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +

  # Add text showing the value of each 100/75/50/25 lines
  annotate("text", x = rep(max(data$id),4), y = c(20, 40, 60, 80), label = c("20", "40", "60", "80") , color="grey", size=3 , angle=0, fontface="bold", hjust=1) +

  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  ylim(-100,120) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm") 
  ) +
  coord_polar() + 
  geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=value+10, label=individual, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=2.5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE ) +

  # Add base line information
  geom_segment(data=base_data, aes(x = start, y = -5, xend = end, yend = -5), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=0.6 , inherit.aes = FALSE )  +
  geom_text(data=base_data, aes(x = title, y = -18, label=group), hjust=c(1,1,0,0), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=4, fontface="bold", inherit.aes = FALSE)

p # se imprime
```

Y este es el resultado

[image: Rplot]

Quisiera que las etiquetas estén alineadas de esta forma.

[image: s]

Las etiquetas de las series están alineadas a una misma distancia desde el eje x pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Bienvenido @conmed a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: @conmed ¿qué problema/dificultad has encontrado al intentar realizar ese cambio? ¿recibes algún error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Consideraciones

Si bien la pregunta tal como está planteada podría generar que esta respuesta obtenga votos negativos, he decidido contestarla porque es interesante y además requiere de un pequeño truco para que se obtenga el resultado solicitado.

En primer lugar al trabajarse en [coordenadas polares](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordenadas_polares) las alturas correspondientes a cada barra en los histogramas mostrados, tienen que ser visualizadas como `radios`.

Entonces para obtener todas las `etiquetas` a la misma distancia (`radio`) del data.frame `data`, se toma el máximo valor de su columna `value` y se le añade `10` o el valor que se necesite.

```
radiusLabel <- max(data$value, na.rm = TRUE) + 10
```

La anterior linea se recomienda hacerla después de crear el citado data.frame.

Entonces en la **séptima fila** (incluir espacios) antes de que acabe el código se debe reemplazar `y=value+10` por `y=radiusLabel`

```
geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=value+10, ...
```

## Arcos

Los arcos son lo que habitualmente se trabaja en el eje X.

Existe un frontera (`boundary`) definida como: `ylim(-100, 120)` la cual limita la altura (`radio`) del gráfico.

Para este caso se reemplaza por `ylim(-100, radiusLabel+100)`, nótese que el límite superior es de acuerdo a lo que se necesita.

Las últimas líneas se definen así:

```
geom_segment(data=base_data, aes(x = start, y = radiusLabel+75, xend = end, yend = radiusLabel+75), colour = "grey",... )  +
geom_text(data=base_data, aes(x = title, y = radiusLabel+95, label=group), colour = "grey",...)
```

El arco previamente definido en `geom_segment` para `A`, `B`, `C` y `D`, tiene la misma estructura que se aprecian en las líneas de código que provienen después del comentario:

```
# Add a val=100/75/50/25 lines. I do it at the beginning to make...
```

## Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Incluí las etiquetas `A`, `B`, `C` y `D` con sus respectivos arcos en la parte exterior del gráfico, si se necesita que tengan el mismo color de las barras, en `geom_text` colocar: `colour = c("#FA9A94", "#A0C153","#5DCFD3","#D59DFF")`